# ScalaTest suite are initialising Play server again and again

Tags: playframework-2.0, scalatest

I am trying to run functional ScalaTest in Play 2.x But Below code in Global.scala is getting executed with each suite call .
override def onStart(app: Application) {
Logger.debug("Application has started .Starting Cache cluster")
.
I do not want this happen. This happen only once when server started .Because we are using HazelCast for catching and later in test suite we are using cached values so we get null pointer exception in this case as onStart gets call everytime and cache value is getting deleted .

Answer (score 0):

I've been experiencing the same thing when running tests under IntelliJ.

In my case, the culprit turned out to be multiple versions of play framework on the class path.

It's not clear from your question whether or not you're running the tests from the command line directly, from sbt, or from IntelliJ, but in my case they worked fine from sbt but not in intellij and I was able to resolve the problem by scrubbing through my submodule dependencies and ensuring they all matched the root project.